# OneToMany mapping in hibernate : Not able to save objects

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have an web application and I am using hibernate for data storage. I have two entity classes `USERS AND FILES` the users can upload the files to the server so users entity is for storing user data and files entity for storing files. In users entity I write following code

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user") 
@Column(nullable = true)
private Collection<Files> files=new ArrayList<Files>();
public Collection<Files> getFiles() {
    return files;
}

public void setFiles(Collection<Files> files) {
    this.files = files;
}
```

and in files entity class

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="uid")
private Users user;
public Users getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(Users user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

whenever I run application the hibernate creates the tables fine with foreign key and all but when I try to save user object by `session.save(u)` It wont get saved. The problem that I can think of is I am not adding any value to the files collection and also just saving the user object not the file object but this is required because it may not be necessary that a user will upload the file. He can just have the account and he may have any files on the server. How can I achieve this in hibernate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157853/hibernate-how-use-cascade-in-annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cascade

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) 
@Column(nullable = true)
private Collection<Files> files=new ArrayList<Files>();
```