# Cascading annotations?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

hi i needed help for studying for my final exam would hope some can help with it.
Cascading does applies to which one of the following annotations?

```
A.  @OneToOne

B.  @OneToMany

C.  @ManyToMany

D.  @ManyToOne

E.  A, B, C, and D

F.  B, C, and D
```

Comment: Couldn't you have googled this and found the answer probably quicker than asking the question here?

Comment: i tried but they are confusing to answer due to e and f.

Comment: just want to confirm that if the answers i choose are right

Comment: I googled and didn't find much but from what I did find and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157853/hibernate-how-use-cascade-in-annotation that 'B' would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is on which of the following annotations is cascading applied, the things you need to google are the annotations themselves:

e.g. [ManyToMany](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html#cascade()). Looks like it has an optional element named `cascade`. Now how about [OneToOne](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html#cascade())? "Ooh, that's a bingo." You already have answer A and C.

And since this only answers the question without you knowing what exactly cascading is, and it's also about your final exam, I'd recommend to read again your preferred source of knowledge about cascading in JPA. It should make it more clear how is it different from the cascading of a raw database, and why this answer actually makes sense.